# Moving space from windows partition to Home directory

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, gparted, partitioning

I Have Windows and Ubuntu 14.04 dual booted and I want to take some space from my Windows partition and move it to my Home directory, Can I do this without deleting my home Directory and making a new one? I can't make more that four primary partitions so I can't just make free space and move the partitions over. I read about extended partitions but I do not understand that.

[image: Gparted window showing my partitions]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible. In gparted just resize the Windows partition a bit and add the space to the Ubuntu partition. Depending on the order of the partitions on your drive you may need to move them in order to get the freed up space near the Ubuntu partition.

BTW: there's a good chance that Windows wants the hard drive to be checked after this just because it sees that something has changed. Just let Windows do the check.

**It is advisable to create a decent backup in case something goes wrong,**

Comment: I edited my Question and you can see I can't move the Ubuntu partition and I can't make a new partition out of the free space because I can only make 4 primary partitions.

Comment: Yes, yoy can. Move sda5 to the left as far as possible in the free space, the move sda3 to the left. Then the free space is on the righthand side of sda3, finally resize sda3 into the free space. Now you have a larger sda3 partition, This sequence of operations may take a long time.

Comment: you have to move / resize the partitions one at a time

Comment: And since sda3 and sda5 are in an extended partition you have to move and resize sda4 first before being ableo work with sda3 and sda5.

Comment: That previous comment is not so clear. You need to move sda5 and sda6 in the extended partition sda4 too.

Comment: how do I move sda 4? it does not have move/resize options

Comment: Show us a screenshot, please.

Comment: do you see the 2nd screenshot in the post? I can not move sda5 to the left.

Comment: Resize, not move sda4 to the left. You said you couldn't move sda4 so I asked to add a screenshot that shows this.

Comment: Oh, ok I added a screenshot to the post.

Comment: Are you by any chance working on a live system? If yes, you should not do that. Get a live cd and boot from that, then try again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21735/discussion-between-ubuntu-blenderer-and-wie5ooma).